# Error when creating DB with a Filestream

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream, sql-server-2012

I'm executing the following sql on a windows 7 os with sql server 2012 express.

```
CREATE DATABASE Archive 
ON
PRIMARY ( 
    NAME = Arch1,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\archdat1.mdf'),
FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup1 CONTAINS FILESTREAM
( 
    NAME = Arch3,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\filestream1')
LOG ON  ( NAME = Archlog1,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\archlog1.ldf')
GO
```

I receive this error:

Msg 5120, Level 16, State 106, Line 1
Unable to open the physical file "c:\data\filestream1". Operating system error 259: "259(No more data is available.)".

This is what I've done before I got here:

- Enabled the service to allow filestream from "sql server configuration manager".
- Enabled the instance to allow a filestream.
- Gave full control on the 'c:\data\' folder to the "NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS2012" account running the sql server service

I'm at a complete loss at this point and any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

I'm installing sql server express on a new windows 7 install to see if this fixes anything.

**UPDATE 2**

Tried running the same sql on a windows xp box with sql server 2008 installed and received this error:

Unable to open the physical file "c:\data\filestream1". Operating system error -2147024891: "0x80070005(Access is denied.)".

**UPDATE 3**

Install on a clean windows 7 machine gives me the exact same error:

Msg 5120, Level 16, State 106, Line 1
Unable to open the physical file "c:\data\filestream1". Operating system error 259: "259(No more data is available.)".

**UPDATE 4**

I was able to get this to work on the windows xp box by changing the "Log on as" to Local System.

**UPDATE 5**

I tried doing the same thing (changing the "Log on as" to Local System) on the windows 7 box and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this.  Turns out it was our internal disk encryption software causing this error.  Disabling the software was not enough.  It had to be completely removed.